# Actual time-based plant growth even when game is off

Tags: unity, savegame

I am developing a game in Unity, and I want a plant to grow based on actual time passed. Basically, if the player turns the game off and turns it back on one day after, the plant should be grown. I'm assuming I would have to somehow access the actual time and compare it. However I'm not sure how this data should be saved. How could I do this?
I would appreciate a brief explanation on what function I could use.
Thank you :)

Comment: In what way would saving a timestamp be different from saving any other game data? I ask because we have [lots of previous Q&A about saving in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+save) that may help you; any techniques shown for saving a number or a string can also save numbers/strings representing date/time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the different ways where and how to store savegame data in Unity are already [covered well enough by many other questions on this website](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity+savegame), so I won't get into that aspect. I will instead focus on how to update plant growth.

I assume that you currently have some Update method somewhere that looks something like this:

```
void Update() {
    // update plant growth
    growth += Time.deltaTime;
    // check if the plant reached the next growth stage
    while (growthLevel < maxGrowthLevel && growth > growthRequiredForNextLevel[growthLevel]( {
        growthLevel++;
        mySpriteRenderer.Sprite = SpriteForGrowthLevel[growthLevel]
    }
}
```

This growing mechanic would need to be refactored into a new method, so that it can process growth progress from any source, not just Time.deltaTime:

```
void Update() {
    CalculateGrowth(Time.deltaTime);
}

public void CalculateGrowth(float secondsPassed) {
    growth += secondsPassed;
    while (growthLevel < maxGrowthLevel && growth > growthRequiredForNextLevel[growthLevel]( {
        growthLevel++;
        mySpriteRenderer.Sprite = SpriteForGrowthLevel[growthLevel]
    }
}
```

Now this method can be called from your savegame loading method to process the time that has passed since the savegame was saved.

How do you find that out? Via the standard C# class [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0). You can get the number of "Ticks" (ten millionth of seconds) that elapsed since the beginning of the century (according to the date and time of the users device) with [`DateTime.Now.Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-ticks). So you just need to store that number in the savegame. When you load the savegame, you again sample the current time by getting that number again and subtract the number from the savegame, using that to instantiate a `TimeSpan` object:

```
long savedTime = // get the number from the savegame data
long currentTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
TimeSpan elapsedSpan = new TimeSpan(currentTime - savedTime);
```

You can then use that TimeSpan object to calculate the number of seconds since the player saved the game, and feed that number to the `CalculateGrowth(float SecondsPassed)` method:

```
plant.CalculateGrowth((float)elapsedSpan.TotalSeconds):
```

Comment: When I've had to serialize/deserialize timestamps in the past, I've gone with `DateTimeOffset.To/FromUnixTimeMilliseconds()` - the millisecond precision is usually more than enough, and as a standard time format it's easy to interop with different tools, like if you later decide to persist plant growth on a server written in node.js etc. It's also insensitive to local time zone/daylight savings time, while [Now.Ticks surprisingly is not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10251851/3064164) - so with Now.Ticks, a player could gain/lose plant growth progress if they change time zones while travelling.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to estimate growth while the game is off:

- When the game is on, do things as normal.
- When the game is about to close, save the current time. You can do that by saving it in a file, or whichever else other way your project handles saved data.
- Next time the game is turned on, get current time, read the time the last time the game closed (by reading the file it was saved in) and compare them.
- Based on the result, apply the changes in your game that would have happened if the game was on the whole time, based on the above result.

This way you can give the illusion to the player that the game was on the whole time and the plant was growing while the player was away.

This has its drawbacks of course, the biggest one being the player could meddle with the system time and confuse the game. There are solutions to these, but once you have the above implementation working, it should be easy to update it to cover any undesired edge cases.

Comment: By my reading, it looks like OP already knows they have to do this: "I'm assuming I would have to somehow access the actual time and compare it" but they're looking for help with the details of *how* to do it, rather than the general strategy described here.

Answer (score -1):

You could save the data on a server (using HTTP requests) when the user turns the game off, then the server calculates, and fetch the data when they turn it on again. Using a server is better than using a temporary game file since game files can be hacked/edited, server files not so easy.

Comment: You say using a server is 'better than using a temporary game file', but there are pros and cons for each, and I would argue that depending on the game in question the cons of using a remote server far outweigh the benefits. If this is for a simple single-player game with no online play or need for competitive validation, preventing cheating by using a relatively expensive server option is unnecessary overhead compared to just saving a start timestamp to a file, then diffing it with the current time.